# handle of DISPID_ONVISIBLE

Tags: c++, com, atl, wtl

I try to hide IWebBrowser2 which I put to DISPID_NEWWINDOW2.

But have no lucky :-(

IWebBrowser2 always visible after Navigate. That is why I try to handle
DISIP_ONVISIBLE and call put_Visible(VARIANT_FALSE) to hide IWebBrowser2
but this event I receive only when call put_Visible() by myself...

How to solve my task?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There's little point in trying to hide popup windows.  They'll just consume resources and ultimately bomb your program.  Set the *Cancel argument to VARIANT_FALSE instead so the popup can't be shown.

Comment: really I need open link in parent IWebBrowser2

Comment: but how to get this link from NEWWINDOW2? and I think navigate in this case is not equal to newwindow

Answer (score 0):

Implement [`NewWindow2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768287%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or [`NewWindow3`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768288%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and set `ppDisp` to a new instance of `IWebBrowser2`.
To make sure that this new instance is not visible use put_Visible or call `ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)` on the control's container.
You could also set `*Cancel = VARIANT_TRUE` to disable the popup altogether.
Implementing `NewWindow3` will give you the destination url.

```
STDMETHODIMP CMyBrowser::OnNewWindow3(IDispatch **ppDisp, 
                                      VARIANT_BOOL *Cancel, 
                                      DWORD dwFlags, 
                                      BSTR bstrUrlContext, 
                                      BSTR bstrUrl)
{
  // spWebBrowser = create a newly instance of IWebBrowser2
  ppDisp = (IDispatch*)spWebBrowser;
  return S_OK;
}
```